# Version control third party packages in golang

Tags: git, go

I am using third party packages in golang and I want to add them to my git repository and when I type the command `git add .` it is giving me the following error

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: github.com/beorn7/perks
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> github.com/beorn7/perks
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached github.com/beorn7/perks
hint:
```

How to make sure that I am version controlling packages correctly and Am I doing the right way of version controlling my third-party packages?

Here is my project structure

```
Project/
|
src/
  |
   github.com/
      |
      packages/
```

My GOPATH is also pointing to project directory

Comment: Use the standard `go dep` tool. Don't fight the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you don't use any package manager, instead you import packages to your $GOPATH. I would advise you to use package manager like `dep` which builds `vendor` directory containing all dependencies. When you run `dep ensure` it will go through your code and pull all the dependencies automatically.

Edit:
As @jubobs since go1.11 you can use `go mod`. Basic premise is the same as `dep`.

Comment: No mention of Go 1.11 modules?

Comment: @xReprisal, Thanks for the reply, I did try to use dep but I get the following error when I run dep init "init failed: unable to determine the import path for the root project Project/src: dep does not currently support using GOPATH/src as the project root"

Comment: @xReprisal, if I use dep and what happens if the third party package owner deletes the repo. How will dep download the package if I want to use my project in another version?

Comment: I think dep did not work because you have your project inside `Project/` which is also `$GOPATH`. Go has very clear guideliness as to how structure your projects. Each project at the very least should reside inside `Project/src` folder.

Comment: If you are afraid of packages being deleted then you can download them to your `$GOPATH` and then manually create vendor folder by copying them inside for each of your project. Though I would strongly advise against that.